# Toolbar is not visible in lollipop?

Tags: android, toolbar

Toolbar is visible in android 4.4 and previous version.when I install my App in lollipop version,Toolbar is hide by the Frame layout. How to fix this problem?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
      tools:openDrawer="hide">
      <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">
          <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
          android:id="@+id/toolbar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
          android:background="@color/white"
         app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
         app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<FrameLayout

    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Java code:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); // enable overriding the default toolbar layout
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: give margin top to your frame layout and then try

Comment: you can add `android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"` Toolbar

Comment: I tried this logic. I work perfectly in kitkat but not working in lollipop

Comment: where is `android:layout_below="@+id/aaa"`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya aaa is a toolbar id.

Comment: There is any need for put my java code for get a solution?

Comment: All the method has worked in kitkat but why it's not working in lollipop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code -

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="hide">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <FrameLayout

            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Create a styles under res/values-v21/style.xml

```
<resources> 

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar"> 
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item> 
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item> 
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item> 
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item> 
</style> 

</resources>
```

Comment: @Gopal: can u post the image with difference?

Comment: I post 2 different version photos?

Comment: try removing the outmost LinearLayout from xml file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100591/discussion-between-kevz-and-gopal).

Comment: yeah... continue in chat

Answer (score 1):

Change your root layout to **RelativeLayout** and put the **FrameLayout** first and everything else comes after the **FrameLayout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <FrameLayout

    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_below="@+id/aaa"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
      tools:openDrawer="hide">
      <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">
          <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
          android:id="@+id/toolbar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
          android:background="@color/white"
         app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
         app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

make it look like this i hope it works

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```